# Content overlapping footer

Tags: css

My slideshow is overlapping my footer. In the source code, I've tried to clear the previous DIV as typically recommended:

```
<div class="clear"></div><!-- /clear any floats -->
```

This is not fixing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to adjust the `footer-wrap` class to add more margin on top:

```
#footer-wrap {
    margin: 100px auto 120px;
}
```

There might be other adjustments necessary but this should fix the issue assuming your content in the sideshow stays the same height.

Answer (score 1):

give this one `<div class="ls-thumbnail-wrapper" style="visibility: visible;">` a `float: left` and it should be fixed